# overriding ToString() with formating arguments

Tags: c#, function, overriding, overloading

Consider the scenario:

```
 int myNumber = 10;
 string formattedNumber = myNumber.ToString("0000"); // output will be "0010"
```

ie., we can format an integer using `ToString()` as like the in above code. i have a class named `myNewClass` in which am over-riding the `ToString()`, my aim is to get a formatted output using overrided ToString() method.

```
 public class myNewClass
        {
            public int MyProperty { get; set; }
            public myNewClass(dynamic x)
            {
                MyProperty = x;
            }
            public override string ToString()
            {
                return MyProperty.ToString();
            }
        }
```

Now am creating an Object of this class as:

```
 myNewClass p = new myNewClass(10);
```

When i called `ToString()` with formatting then it wont compile:

```
  var m = p.ToString("0000");//gives error that "no overloaded method Tostring() takes one argument."
```

So i have changed the function signature as like the following:

```
  public override string ToString(string format)
        {
            return MyProperty.ToString(format);
        }
```

Again result in the same as: `No suitable method found to override`

**My question is that How can i achieve overriding ToString() with formating arguments**

Comment: The base class of your `myNewClass`, `System.Object`, does not define a method `public virtual string ToString(string)`, so you cannot "override" it. Frankly, the code fragments you show shouldn't even compile. Try removing the "override" specification from your `ToString(string)` method.

Comment: Blindy answered your question. You should consider to implement [IFormattable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iformattable.tostring(v=vs.110).aspx) to use formatted values in [string.Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.String.Format(v=VS.110).aspx) too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Remove the `override` keyword and you're set. You're not overriding anything in this case since `System.Object` only has `string ToString()`. What you're doing is adding an additional function call to the existing one (just like all the numeric value types do in the framework itself).